# Why must Lucene Token Filter classes be declared "final"?

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize

According to [Solr's blog](http://solr.pl/en/2012/05/14/developing-your-own-solr-filter/), Lucene requires that TokenFilter subclasses must be declared final.  What is the advantage of final classes in this context?  It makes it impossible to extend the functionality of an existing TokenFilter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TokenFilter` extends `TokenStream`, and its Javadoc says:

> The `TokenStream`-API in Lucene is based on the decorator pattern.
>   Therefore all non-abstract subclasses must be final or have at least a
>   final implementation of `incrementToken()`! This is checked when Java
>   assertions are enabled.

For example, `StandardFilter` is not marked `final` (only `incrementToken()` is).

So if you want to extend existing `TokenFilter` it's best to do this via delegation.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting.  I understand that the decorator pattern tries to prevent excessive subclassing, but I didn't know it explicitly forbid it.  Is there anything about subclassing that would break the decorator pattern?

Comment: I personally think this is just defensive coding to ensure that sensitive piece of code doesn't get lost in subclasses.